# isset($_POST['x']) only works if the submit button name="submit"

Tags: php, xhtml

I'm having trouble using postback because I've more than one form and `isset` only works with `name="submit"` buttons.

My code will work fine if I use `name="submit"` but if I changed the name to something else, `isset($_POST['somethingelse'])` will always be false, why does this happen?

EDIT:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick ="validate(document.getElementById('form')); return false;" />

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) <-- works as expected



<input type="submit" name="asdf" value="Submit" onclick ="validate(document.getElementById('form')); return false;" />


if (isset($_POST['asdf'])) <-- does not works as expected
```

---

EDIT2:

```
<?php
$validated = false;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // preserve form values by storing the values from $_POST into variables
    $test = $_POST['test'];
    // validated is now true as submit button only submits if validated (script)
    $validated = true;
} else {
    // make variables empty as there's no values to preserve
        $test = '';
}

if (!$validated) {
?>
<form id="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
<p>Test: <input type="text" name="test" size="20" value="<?php echo $test ?>" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick ="validate(); return false;" /></p>
<?php } ?>
```

For example here, works as expected (I can keep the values) as name="submit" and if (isset($_POST['submit'])) is true when the button submits but if I change both the name="" and the if (isset($_POST[''])) then it will not work as the isset is returning false (even though the button submits).

Comment: No, there must be another problem. Post the relevant code.

Comment: Post your html and php code

Comment: And check what `$_POST` contains. isset will return true if asdf is in $_POST. If it is not it will return false.

Comment: show your full form code?

Comment: Code is fine. The problem is something else. Strip everything down - remove your javascript and any other non essential parts - leave just the inputs, the submit button, and the `isset` code. That should work. Then start adding everything back piece by piece until it breaks.

Comment: It does not work even with the most basic of examples. As long as my submit button isn't called submit, it's never set even though it is submitted ... I tried on different versions of php and also had my friend try it for me, same results.

Comment: You still haven't given a complete example. In your post you say you have more than one form. So those have, I presume, different IDs and differently named submit buttons. Show the whole thing!

Answer (score 2):

It's normal because only the clicked submit button is set and not the second, if you click on submit button with name **submit** `isset($_POST['submit'])` will give you **true** and `isset($_POST['asdf'])` **false**, and if you click on **asdf** `isset($_POST['submit'])` gives **false** and `isset($_POST['asdf'])` **true**, i tested it and it works without any problem.

Test code:

```
<?php
$validated = false;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // preserve form values by storing the values from $_POST into variables
    $test = "submit";
    // validated is now true as submit button only submits if validated (script)
    $validated = true;
} 
else if(isset($_POST['asdf'])){
        $test = "asdf";
    // validated is now true as submit button only submits if validated (script)
    $validated = true;
}
else {
    // make variables empty as there's no values to preserve
        $test = '';
}
if (!$validated) {
echo $test;
} ?>
<form id="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
<p>Test: <input type="text" name="test" size="20" value="<?php echo $test ?>" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick ="validate(); return false;" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="asdf" value="Submit" onclick ="validate(document.getElementById('form')); return false;" />
</p>
```